# How to get Emacs to know that a symbol has a function definition

Tags: functions, byte-compilation, warning, symbol-function

While reading the source file `prelude-ivy.el` in the [Prelude modules directory](https://github.com/bbatsov/prelude/blob/master/modules/prelude-ivy.el), I saw that there was a warning associated with "here" in the last line, specifically that `prelude-required-packages` was not known to be a defined function.

I recognize that this is not exactly devastating but I am curious to understand better how to make a symbol "known to be defined" as a function.  I tried a few things, like `(require 'prelude-packages)` but only moved the harmless warning around. I'm guessing that if I understand why this warning is being reported, a fix will be readily evident.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your question is a little confusing, but I suspect you actually mean that you've *byte-compiled* the `prelude-ivy.el` library (as opposed to "reading the source file"), and that the compiler has produced a warning that the function `prelude-require-packages` is not known to be defined (n.b. *not* "prelude-require**d**-packages", which does not appear anywhere in the file; and the warning would be quite specific about it being a function, rather than a "symbol", which is not known to be defined).

The warning would look like this:

> In end of data:
>   prelude-ivy.el:71:1:Warning: the function ‘prelude-require-packages’ is not
>       known to be defined.

(And for future reference, if you have a question about a warning or error message, you should always copy and paste that message into your question -- doing so here would have eliminated all the confusion.)

The message tells us that the byte-compiler got all the way through the file and never encountered a definition for that function, even though it was used earlier in the file:

```el
(prelude-require-packages '(ivy swiper counsel))
```

The warning (which will indeed be harmless in practice) can be silenced by informing the byte-compiler *where* the function `prelude-require-packages` is defined:

```el
(declare-function 'prelude-require-packages "prelude-packages")
```

See <kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>i</kbd><kbd>g</kbd> `(elisp)Declaring Functions`

Comment: Thank you both Drew and Phils for providing an answer and teaching how to write a better question. Both are very much appreciated.